# Preposition at - which sentence is correct

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct and why?

> I was at friend's yesterday.
>
> I was at a friend's yesterday.
>
> I was at the friend's yesterday.
>
> I was at my friend's yesterday.

or

> I was at a friend yesterday.
>
> I was at the friend yesterday.
>
> I was at my friend yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the second group are correct. You can be "at" a place, not a person. We normally say you are "with" a person.

The first group is correct because there is an assumed noun that is omitted, probably "home". "Friend's" is an adjective modifying this assumed noun. So what the sentence really means is "I was at a friend's HOME yesterday." In context, the assumed noun might be "office" or some other place associated with your friend.

Within the first group, numbers two and four -- "a friend's" and "my friend's" -- are correct. I'd say that "my friend's" is the best, but "a friend's" is commonly used. If you talk about "a friend", we normally understand you to mean your friend, unless you specify otherwise. ("Yesterday Bob's friend Sally said ...") (I'm suddenly reminded of a wonderful dialog from "Buffy the Vampire Slayer": "Who are you?" "A friend." "Maybe I don't need a friend." "I didn't say I was YOUR friend.")

Number one, "at friend's", would most likely be incorrect because, as I said earlier, the assumed noun is "home" or something similar, which is singular and not a proper noun, and so calls for an article. It could possibly be correct if in context you were talking about multiple places, so the assumed noun is "homes" rather than "home". But "friend's" is singular, one friend, and generally any given friend has only one home. I think for most fluent speakers, if there was more than one place, they wouldn't rely on assumed nouns. They'd say, "I was at friends' homes yesterday." Or, "I was at two of my friend's homes" if one friend had many homes.

Number four, "the friend's", is unlikely. In context "the" could refer either to "friend" or the assumed "home". "The friend" is unlikely as it implies you only have one friend. It could make sense in context if you are contrasting two people, one of whom is a friend and the other not. Like, "I was talking to a friend and a stranger yesterday. Then I went to the friend's home." That is, making clear you went to the home of the friend and not the home of the stranger, and to the home of the friend you mentioned a moment ago and not some other friend. (Again, "home" could be dropped: "Then I went to the friend's.") If your intent was that "the" referred to the assumed noun, you probably wouldn't drop it but would spell it out. Like, "I talked to a friend about his home and his office. Then I went to the friend's home." This one gets debatable, I think.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your comprehensive answer. So, I can omit "home" safely. A: Where were you yesterday? B: I was at a friend's. / I was at my friend's. It's correct, right? One more question: Can I use "house" instead of "home"? What are you more likely to say as a native speaker: I was at a friend's. / I was at my friend's. / I was at a friend's home. / I was at a friend's house. / I was at my friend's house.?

Comment: Yes, "at a friend's" or "at my friend's" are correct. RE "house": Yes, you could certainly say "house". I used "home" above because if you say "at my friend's" without giving a noun, we assume you mean his home, but we don't know what kind of home it is: a house, apartment, condo, trailer, etc. If you specify, then you should use the word for the appropriate type of home. I guess if you were there yesterday you'd know, but if you said, "I was invited to go to my friend's tomorrow", you might not know.